# Renamed index.php then Slim API stopped working

Tags: php, api, slim

I had my slim API working, but then i decided to rename my index.php. After renaming it, it wouldn't work. So I renamed it back to index.php and deleted the other index.php. However, now it won't work at all.

My index looks as follows:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require './vendor/autoload.php';
require './config/db.php';

//authenticator


// routes
require './routes/product.php';
require './routes/login.php';
require './routes/cart.php';
require './routes/wishlist.php';


// run app
$app->run();
```

My product route looks as follows:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// all entries

$app->get('/api/products/all', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product_endpoint";

    try
    {
      $db = new DB();
      $conn = $db->connect();

      $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
      $product = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

      $db = null;
      $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($product));
      return $response
        ->withHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(200);
    } catch (PDOException $e)
    {
      $error = ["message" => $e->getMessage()];
      $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($error));
      return $response
        ->withHeader('content-type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Before I renamed my index.php this worked perfectly, however now I'm just greeted with "page not found" when i navigate to my api endpoint.

index.php is located at root and the route is located in a file called "route".

Can anyone kindly assist? Thank you.

Comment: In Slim you only need one public index.php file that a acts as the front controller.

Comment: index is the default file used by all webservers... if you rename your index.php file, maybe you need to modify your .htaccess file or your web server configuration, to redirect all request to that file.